# uwsgi: no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode

Tags: flask, uwsgi

In my uwsgi config, I have these options:

```
[uwsgi]
chmod-socket = 777
socket = 127.0.0.1:9031
plugins = python
pythonpath = /adminserver/
callable = app
master = True
processes = 4
reload-mercy = 8
cpu-affinity = 1
max-requests = 2000
limit-as = 512
reload-on-as = 256
reload-on-rss = 192
no-orphans
vacuum
```

My app structure looks like this:

```
/adminserver
   app.py
   ...
```

My `app.py` has these bits of code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5003, debug=True)
```

The result is that when I try to curl my server, I get this error:

```
Wed Sep 11 23:28:56 2013 - added /adminserver/ to pythonpath.
Wed Sep 11 23:28:56 2013 - *** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
Wed Sep 11 23:28:56 2013 - *** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

What do the `module` and `callable` options do? The docs say:

> **module, wsgi** Argument: string
>
> Load a WSGI module as the application. The module (sans .py) must be
>   importable, ie. be in PYTHONPATH.
>
> This option may be set with -w from the command line.
>
> **callable** Argument: string Default: application
>
> Set default WSGI callable name.

Comment: Your current configuration doesn't seem to have a `module` or `wsgi` key ...

Answer (score 11):

### Module

A module in Python maps to a file on disk - when you have a directory like this:

```
/some-dir
    module1.py
    module2.py
```

If you start up a python interpreter while the current working directory is `/some-dir` you will be able to import each of the modules:

```
some-dir$ python
>>> import module1, module2
# Module1 and Module2 are now imported
```

Python searches `sys.path` (and a few other things, [see the docs on `import` for more information](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/import.html#finders-and-loaders)) for a file that matches the name you are trying to import.  uwsgi uses Python's import process under the covers to load the module that contains your WSGI application.

### Callable

The WSGI PEPs ([333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/) and [3333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/)) specify that a WSGI application [is a callable that takes two arguments and returns an iterable that yields bytestrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#specification-details):

```
# simple_wsgi.py
# The simplest WSGI application
HELLO_WORLD = b"Hello world!\n"

def simple_app(environ, start_response):
    """Simplest possible application object"""
    status = '200 OK'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain')]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [HELLO_WORLD]
```

uwsgi needs to know the name of a symbol inside of your module that maps to the WSGI application callable, so it can pass in the environment and the `start_response` callable - essentially, it needs to be able to do the following:

```
wsgi_app = getattr(simple_wsgi, 'simple_app')
```

### TL;PC (Too Long; Prefer Code)

A simple parallel of what uwsgi is doing:

```
# Use `module` to know *what* to import
import simple_wsgi

# construct request environment from user input
# create a callable to pass for start_response
# and then ...

# use `callable` to know what to call
wsgi_app = getattr(simple_wsgi, 'simple_app')

# and then call it to respond to the user
response = wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: Should the `module` defined in my `uwsgi` config file be the python file that contains the `simple_app` wgsi application? It doesn't work, but I'm not sure how `uwsgi` finds the app it's referring to in the error, `no app loaded`.

Comment: @RosePerrone - as I understand it, yes `module` should match the name of the file on disk you want to import.  The error message is not referring to an app, it is referring to the *lack* of one, and it just uses the generic name.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone else having this problem, if you are sure your configuration is correct, you should check your uWSGI version.

Ubuntu 12.04 LTS provides 1.0.3. Removing that and using pip to install 2.0.4 resolved my issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your configuration whether is correct.

my `uwsgi.ini` configuration:

```
[uwsgi]
chdir=/home/air/repo/Qiy
uid=nobody
gid=nobody
module=Qiy.wsgi:application
socket=/home/air/repo/Qiy/uwsgi.sock
master=true
workers=5
pidfile=/home/air/repo/Qiy/uwsgi.pid
vacuum=true
thunder-lock=true
enable-threads=true
harakiri=30
post-buffering=4096
daemonize=/home/air/repo/Qiy/uwsgi.log
```

then use `uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini` to run uwsgi.

if not work, you `rm -rf` the `venv` directory, and re-initial the venv, and re-try my step.

I re-initial the `venv` solved my issue, seems the problem is when I `pip3 install` some packages of `requirements.txt`, and upgrade the pip, then install `uwsgi` package. so, I delete the `venv`, and re-initial my virtual environment.